# HDF5 throws errors, unless I inline subroutine

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I recently started exploring the HDF5 library for Fortran, and I came across some curious behaviour that I don't understand. The code below compiles just fine, but when I try to run the code, I get a very long list of errors originating from the subroutine `HDF_init_ot`. When I place this subroutine inside the caller subroutine `HDF_init` (as I did in `HDF_init2`), everything works perfectly fine. Why does this happen?

**The code**:

```
!===============================================================================
! This subroutine makes a call to an external subroutine HDF_init_ot,
! which throws an error
!===============================================================================
subroutine HDF_init()

    use hdf5

    character(len=11), parameter :: filename = "output.hdf5"
    character(len=2), parameter :: group_ot = "ot"

    integer(HID_T) :: file_handle, ot_handle
    integer :: error

    ! Create a new HDF file
    call h5open_f(error)
    call h5fcreate_f(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_handle, error)

    ! Create a new group
    call h5gcreate_f(file_handle, group_ot, ot_handle, error)
    ! Call to subroutine
    call HDF_init_ot(ot_handle)
    ! Close group
    call h5gclose_f(ot_handle, error)

    ! Close file
    call h5fclose_f(file_handle, error)
    call h5close_f(error)

end subroutine HDF_init

!===============================================================================
! The culprit subroutine
!===============================================================================
subroutine HDF_init_ot(ot_handle)

    use hdf5

    character(len=1), parameter :: dset_t = "t"

    integer(HID_T) :: ot_handle, ot_space_handle
    integer(HID_T) :: data_handle

    integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(1) :: ot_dims, ot_max_dims

    integer :: error, rank

    ! Define rank and dimensions
    rank = 1
    ot_dims = (/0/)
    ot_max_dims = (/H5S_UNLIMITED_F/)

    ! Create a data space
    call h5screate_simple_f(rank, ot_dims, ot_space_handle, error, ot_max_dims)
    ! Create a data set within the space
    call h5dcreate_f(   ot_handle, dset_t, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, ot_space_handle, &
                                        data_handle, error)
    ! Close the data set
    call h5dclose_f(data_handle, error)
    ! Close the data space
    call h5sclose_f(ot_space_handle, error)

end subroutine HDF_init_ot

!===============================================================================
! When I inline HDF_init_ot into the subroutine below, everything works
!===============================================================================
subroutine HDF_init2()

    use hdf5

    character(len=11), parameter :: filename = "output.hdf5"
    character(len=2), parameter :: group_ot = "ot"
    character(len=1), parameter :: dset_t = "t"

    integer(HID_T) :: file_handle, ot_handle, ot_space_handle, data_handle
    integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(1) :: ot_dims, ot_max_dims

    integer :: error, rank

    rank = 1
    ot_dims = (/0/)
    ot_max_dims = (/H5S_UNLIMITED_F/)

    call h5open_f(error)
    call h5fcreate_f(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_handle, error)

    call h5gcreate_f(file_handle, group_ot, ot_handle, error)
    call h5screate_simple_f(rank, ot_dims, ot_space_handle, error, ot_max_dims)
    call h5dcreate_f(   ot_handle, dset_t, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, ot_space_handle, &
                                        data_handle, error)

    call h5dclose_f(data_handle, error)
    call h5sclose_f(ot_space_handle, error)
    call h5gclose_f(ot_handle, error)

    call h5fclose_f(file_handle, error)
    call h5close_f(error)

end subroutine HDF_init2

!===============================================================================
! Main program
!===============================================================================
program test

    implicit none

    ! This one throws errors
    call HDF_init()
    ! This one does not
    call HDF_init2()

end program test
```

**The error**:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.16) thread 140274482874112:

#000: ../../../src/H5D.c line 194 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#001: ../../../src/H5Dint.c line 453 in H5D__create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#002: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1638 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
major: Links
minor: Unable to initialize object

#003: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1882 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
major: Symbol table
minor: Unable to insert object

#004: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
major: Symbol table
minor: Object not found

#005: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
major: Symbol table
minor: Callback failed

#006: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1685 in H5L_link_cb(): unable to create object
major: Object header
minor: Unable to initialize object

#007: ../../../src/H5O.c line 3016 in H5O_obj_create(): unable to open object
major: Object header
minor: Can't open object

#008: ../../../src/H5Doh.c line 293 in H5O__dset_create(): unable to create dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#009: ../../../src/H5Dint.c line 1056 in H5D__create(): unable to construct layout information
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#010: ../../../src/H5Dcontig.c line 422 in H5D__contig_construct(): extendible contiguous non-external dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Feature is unsupported

HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.16) thread 140274482874112:

#000: ../../../src/H5D.c line 415 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Inappropriate type

HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.16) thread 140274482874112:

#000: ../../../src/H5D.c line 194 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to create dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#001: ../../../src/H5Dint.c line 453 in H5D__create_named(): unable to create and link to dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#002: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1638 in H5L_link_object(): unable to create new link to object
major: Links
minor: Unable to initialize object

#003: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1882 in H5L_create_real(): can't insert link
major: Symbol table
minor: Unable to insert object

#004: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
major: Symbol table
minor: Object not found

#005: ../../../src/H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
major: Symbol table
minor: Callback failed

#006: ../../../src/H5L.c line 1685 in H5L_link_cb(): unable to create object
major: Object header
minor: Unable to initialize object

#007: ../../../src/H5O.c line 3016 in H5O_obj_create(): unable to open object
major: Object header
minor: Can't open object

#008: ../../../src/H5Doh.c line 293 in H5O__dset_create(): unable to create dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#009: ../../../src/H5Dint.c line 1056 in H5D__create(): unable to construct layout information
major: Dataset
minor: Unable to initialize object

#010: ../../../src/H5Dcontig.c line 422 in H5D__contig_construct(): extendible contiguous non-external dataset
major: Dataset
minor: Feature is unsupported

HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.16) thread 140274482874112:

#000: ../../../src/H5D.c line 415 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
major: Invalid arguments to routine
minor: Inappropriate type
```

**Edit**:

I found that when I remove `ot_max_dims` from the `h5screate_simple_f` call, everything runs as expected. Curiously, if I define `ot_max_dims` within `HDF_init` and pass this as an extra parameter to `HDF_init_ot`, things also work. This suggests to me that `H5S_UNLIMITED_F` is a parameter that is private to `HDF_init()`, possibly tied to the API instance (i.e. to `h5open_f`)?